# Pass Objects to WCF Endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have a WCF service that has a service method, which takes in a parameter of type object[].  I want to pass different kinds of objects based on a variety of workflows.  When I attempt to pass any concrete objects that inherit from the base object type, I get the following error:

```
'Error in line 1 position 446. Element 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:anyType' contains data of the 
'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/...' data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any 
type that maps to this contract. Add the type corresponding to '...' to the list of known types - for 
example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed 
to DataContractSerializer.'
```

**Question**

How can I pass a plain old object of any type to a WCF service and interpret (cast to) the type I want within the WCF service method?

At a high level what I want to do is pass an instance of the plain type object to WCF.  Is that even possible?

Comment: As it says in the error message, and if your known types are limited and are not subject to change in time, add `[KnownType(typeof(...))]`

Comment: What would go inside of the '...'?  Would that be typeof(object), because I want to pass plain objects.  Also where would I add that KnownType attribute on the contract or the data class?

Comment: What do you mean by plain objects? `new object()` ? Whatever you pass to your service should match to a type known by the server. Otherwise, how could you cast it to the real type?

Comment: Lets say (outside WCF) I have a method that takes in an object.  I can pass it an Animal instance right?  The question is how do I do that in WCF.  Once I then have the object I can cast it to Animal or a Person or whatever I want to try.  You can pass any object and turn it into JSON.  How do I pass any object and turn it into generic XML.  Is there some sort of XmlSerialization trick that I can do here?

Comment: You cannot just say `[KnownType(typeof(object))]`. Put yourself in the deserializer's shoes. You are given a box with something inside it and you don't know what it is. Yet someone expects you to know what is inside without telling you even the list of items that the thing can be. WCF services are called by many ways but all of them requires a transformation from either text or binary data so to transform correctly you should know what is inside.

Comment: Do you want the de-serialization to occur automatically or are you open to de-serializing yourself

Comment: I see what you are saying, but like I mentioned JSON serialization work in a way that I can say I don't care what the type is, just turn it into JSON right?  Plus I am trying to mimick an existing SOAP service that does have the capability I'm talking about already (not written in c# mind you).

Comment: I'm open to whatever gets it working :).  How would I go about serializing myself, and can I do it for just one method or type, or do I have to do I have to replace the serializer completely?

Comment: The advantage of json (and also binary serialization) in .net is, they can specify the type information along with the data. This is not so for XmlSerialization which generates code and compiles it when the XmlSerializer is instantiated given a type for the first time. Therefore, it has to know. You can use one trick, the [XmlInclude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.type?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Well thanks.  I'll look into that.

Comment: Also, if you are open to de-serializing yourself, many doors open. Accept a byte[] and deserialize using BinaryFormatter for example. Accept string and de-serialize using JsonConvert (assuming that the received json has type information inside.). Both methods assume that the type exists on the server which is essential.

Comment: I am open to trying anything on the server-side, but unfortunately the task is to leave the client code the same, as many of our customers already have it in place.  I'm basically tasked with replacing the server side without disrupting the existing client-side code that is already out there in the wild.

Comment: I see. Then you are stuck with the DataContractSerializer and KnownTypes I guess.

Comment: Do incoming `object`s have a common structure (i.e., can you make a base class and a bunch of deriving classes to represent those objects)? Or are they a mix of primitive types (int, string etc.) and DTO objects?

Comment: The incoming object can be one of several different types.  There is no inheritance involved.  I basically want to pass in an object of any type from the client, and then cast it to any type on the server @HeyJude

Comment: Also, do you expect different types of objects in the same incoming `object[]` instance? e.g., would the incoming array look like `[ "test", 1 ]`?

Comment: @HeyJude Yes, the incoming objects will always be each one of a series of complex types and never primitives.

Comment: Then I'm not sure why `KnownType` doesn't work for you. Can you give, say, 2 examples of an incoming `object[]` content?

Comment: I don't think examples are necessary.  I tried using KnownType of object.  The objects coming in are just C# object instantiations of classes that have no other inheritance other than object.  An example is public class MyObject { public int Foo = 0; } I want to pass an instance of that as an object.  It is that simple.  How do you use a known type of type object is the question I guess.

Comment: What I'd like to see is if you're passing different object types in the same `object[]` instance, as this won't work. For the simple case, there shouldn't be a problem, but see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3289857/3002584).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  That is exactly what I'm trying to do.  Pass different object types in the same object[] instance.  What is crazy is that the legacy service I'm replacing does this just fine, so there has to be a way to do it - the WSDL defines it somehow.  I've combed through the WSDL and can't figure out how its happening.

Comment: You should add here you're wsdl, then. Also, you should really add here your current WCF c# and config code.